# API access for workbench render settings

Tags: python, workbench-render-engine

In Blender 2.8 how do I change the settings for the workbench render properties via python? The settings for the workbench *render*, not a viewport.
For example if I manually change the lighting to FLAT, then the info panel reflects the command

```
bpy.context.scene.shading.light = 'FLAT'
```

but when running this myself it says that 'Scene' doesn't contain the attribute 'shading'. Same result if I directly access the scene object through bpy.data.

In the same render settings panel, in the 'Film' dropdown I can successfully change the Alpha Mode with `bpy.context.scene.render.alpha_mode = "TRANSPARENT"`, but the settings related to the render engine have no such access that I can find.

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].display.shading.light = 'FLAT'
```

or

```
bpy.context.scene.display.shading.light = 'FLAT'
```

(thanks to @nicklamer on #blenderpython)

Comment: Also works for accessing `bpy.context.scene.display.shading.color_type`