# How can I set render settings using bpy?

Tags: python, properties

I want to set my render settings to specific configuration , as in the following image

[image]

I tried the following script to attempt it

```
bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'BLENDER_WORKBENCH'
bpy.context.scene.shading.light = 'MATCAP'
bpy.context.scene.shading.color_type = 'OBJECT'
bpy.context.scene.shading.show_shadows = True
```

( I just used the script I was getting in the blender console (if that's what we call it), I am new to blender so i just try to replicate the methodology i used in maya I guess things are a bit different here ) from here : [image]

But I am getting the following error :

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 201, in <module>
  File "\Text", line 191, in turnaround
AttributeError: 'Scene' object has no attribute 'shading'
```

Any help or even reference where I can get this done/look more about it would be really great.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [API access for workbench render settings](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132893/api-access-for-workbench-render-settings)

Comment: That also seems to be a bug. It should be reported if it isn't yet. Wrong information is displayed.

Comment: @Crantisz Yes Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've been struggling with the same issue. You can find the actual command hovering your mouse over the setting in the UI ; for example, I tried `bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].render.engine = 'BLENDER_WORKBENCH` in the *interactive* Python console, hit Enter, and it changed my render engine to Workbench. The 'console' you posted an image of shows different commands, I don't know the reason why. It showed nothing when I changed with Python, but when I used my mouse to revert to Cycles, this displayed `bpy.context.scene.render.engine = 'CYCLES'`...